# I can't modify my SVG component in my React Application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I have been trying to fill the color of an SVG component in React, but it won't work.

I've tried using an image tag to React. However, I read on the React docs that CSS with the img tag isn't supported.

```
//css
.dotSvg{
  position: relative;
  fill: #5AE2EB;
}
//React
//import
import { ReactComponent as Dot } from './dot.svg';

//code itself
<div className="home">
  <Dot className="dotSvg"/>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to use fill and other kinds of SVG modifiable attributes.

update:This is my css file code setup. .dotSvg is a item of .container class. Still need help

```
.container{ display: grid;
 text-align: center; 
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto; 
position: sticky; 
top: 0; 
}

 .dotSvg{ cursor: pointer; 
position: r
elative; 
fill: #5AE2EB; 
}

///svg file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2 2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;"><circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" style="fill-opacity:0;"/></svg>
```

Solved! I found out that the svg had a fill-opacity: 0; style on it so I removed it or you could put it to one to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the svg style fill-opacity:0 from the svg file itself. You could also change the 0 to 1 if you that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Most common case is that .svg file is converted/edited or not properly exported, without that file the easiest way to change e.g. color is to open that file in any text/code editor, copy code without xml tag so from svg tag..to closing /svg tag and paste directly into code.

Then you can easly style whole element or some parts of it e.g.

```
.yourSvgWrapperDivClass svg g {
    fill: #0000FF;
}
```

You can also refer directly to some elements of the svg file/code (just inspect it) and try style g/path or rect elements.

Comment: I tried this and it had the same result. It has a wrapper around it such as     
 ```.container{
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    /* grid-template-rows: 100px 300px; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.dotSvg{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  fill: #5AE2EB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to handle this would be to use the SVG code itself as a component, then use props to pass in the fill colors as needed.

```
// App
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="switcher">
          <IconOffice />
        </div>
        <IconOffice bookfill="orange" bookside="#39B39B" bookfront="#76CEBD" />
        <IconOffice width="200" height="200" />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

// Icon
const IconOffice = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      width: '100',
      height: '200',
      bookfill: '#f77b55',
      bookside: '#353f49',
      bookfront: '#474f59'
    };
  },
 render() {
   return (
     <svg className="office" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} viewBox="0 0 188.5 188.5" aria-labelledby="title">
        <title id="title">Office Icon</title>
        <g className="cls-2">
          <circle id="background" className="cls-3" cx="94.2" cy="94.2" r="94.2"/>
          <path className="cls-4" d="M50.3 69.8h10.4v72.51H50.3z"/>
          <path fill={this.props.bookside} d="M50.3 77.5h10.4v57.18H50.3z"/>
          <path fill={this.props.bookfront} d="M60.7 77.5h38.9v57.19H60.7z"/>
          <path className="cls-7" d="M60.7 69.8h38.9v7.66H60.7z"/>
          <path className="cls-5" d="M60.7 134.7h38.9v7.66H60.7z"/>
          ...
      </svg>
   )
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#main"));
```

https://css-tricks.com/creating-svg-icon-system-react/